# The type or namespace name 'SqlBulkCopy' could not be found

Tags: c#, excel, namespaces, sqlbulkcopy

can someone help me please to fix that error.
this is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data;
using System.Configuration;

OleDbConnection ExcelCon = new OleDbConnection();
ExcelCon.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\pc\\Documents\\ExcellTest.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes\"";
SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection();
SqlCon.ConnectionString = @"workstation id = PC-PC; user id=sa;Password=sapassword; data source=pc-pc; persist security info=True; initial catalog=CleanPayrollTest2";
string sSQLTable = "TestExcell";
string sClearSQL = "DELETE FROM " + sSQLTable;
SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sClearSQL, SqlCon);
SqlCon.Open();
SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlCon.Close(); 
DataTable dtSchema;
dtSchema = ExcelCon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand ("select * FROM [" + dtSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "]", ExcelCon);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(Command);
DataSet ds = new DataSet ();
da.Fill(ds);
dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    OleDbDataReader dr = Command.ExecuteReader();
SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sSqlConnectionString); 
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = sSQLTable; 
while (dr.Read())
{
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
}
```

Errors:

-The type or namespace name 'bulkCopy' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

-The type or namespace name 'SqlBulkCopy' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

-The type or namespace name 'OleDbConn' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you including Using System.Data.SqlClient; at the top of your class definition?

Comment: The error says it all. The types cannot be found because you are either missing a `using` directive, or an assembly reference. Add a `using` clause specifying the correct namespace, and/or add the appropriate assembly references. If you would have taken a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx), you would've seen the `SqlBulkCopy`class is in the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace in the `System.Data.dll` assembly.

Comment: i assure you that i did wrote all the using stuff ...

Comment: @Nejthe it would have been nice to read that in your question. Did you also add a reference to `System.Data.dll`? Does the project give other build errors?

Comment: how can i add a reference to System.Data.dll?
and no, this is the only errors
thank You so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class belongs on [`System.Data.SqlClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx) namespace. Add your code as a namespace it like;

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

This namespace contains in `System.Data.dll`

For adding reference in Visual Studio, you can right click "`Reference`" in Solution Explorer and click `Add Reference`.

[image]

Search `System.Data` in search box, and Add the top result `System.Data` dll to your solution.

[image]

Check out for more information for [How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from *MSDN*.

Comment: @Nejthe What is the type of `bulkCopy` and `OleDbConn` then ?

Comment: @Nejthe Are `bulkCopy` and `OleDbConn` defined in your same method ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a reference to `System.Data.dll` in your project and do you have a `using System.Data.SqlClient` statement in your file?

Comment: Yes i have a using System.Data.SqlClient statement
But How can i Check if i have referenxe to System.Data.dll ? 
sorry i'm new in c#

Comment: Within Visual Studio, expand your project and you should see a `References` folder. Expand that and check you can see `System.Data` in the list.

Comment: @Nejthe All I can suggest then is that you update your answer with the full class definition (i.e. including your using statements, class declaration, etc). Please also make sure you format your code so it is more readable.

Comment: Sorry If it's not readable well.. Will you check the question now, I added the using statements

Comment: I copied your code into a new class and got the following build errors: `Cannot resolve symbol dataGrid1` and `Cannot resolve symbol sSqlConnectionString`. I can't help any further as clearly this is not all the code.

Comment: Don't worry Daniel I really appreciate your help.. I'm gonna try another method

Answer (score 1):

Install NuGet package: System.Data.SqlClient

[image]