# error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NUnitLite' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, nunit

I have this code written to launch my selenium test scripts (.cs file)

```
using NUnitLite;
namespace myProject
{

    public class Runner
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
                return new AutoRun().Execute(args);
        }
    }
}
```

when I try to run this using command line it throws

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NUnitLite' could not be found (are you missing a using
        directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I tried adding the NUnitLite.dll to reference but it does not allow me saying  `This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.`

Comment: I refered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481047/the-type-or-namespace-name-sqlbulkcopy-could-not-be-found
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773062/nunit-dll-issue-namespace-cant-be-found
but it did not help.

Comment: Please provide more complete information. Where are your tests? In the same project as Main? Elsewhere? Which of your assemblies reference NUnitLite and the nunit framework? Are all the assemblies created in the same output directory or if not, what is the output structure?